# Facebook keeps sending friend notifications despite settings set otherwise

Tags: facebook, notifications

While I am trying to surf, all of these Facebook notifications flood the right side of my screen one after the other. It freezes my computer and I have to wait until I can click one of the Xs on a notification.

I went to my account settings and have completely unchecked anything that says anyone or any application can send me notifications, but they still continue.

How can I stop all these notifications?

Answer (score 1):

Please consider submitting a bug report under the [Notifications Automatically Turned On](http://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=notification_settings) form.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're talking about the sidebar. You can easily hide both and the settings will stick as long as your Facebook cookies don't get deleted.

At the bottom left of your screen you'll find the Hide sidebar button (see top part of screenshot below.

If you don't see that or have already clicked it then find the `Hide Ticker` button at the top right of your screen (see bottom part of the screenshot below).

[image: Hide Sidebar & Hide Ticker]